Is it possible to include an equation with a condition that depends on a variable in another equation?
I have a question regarding GAMS basics. Is it possible to include an equation with a condition that depends on a variable in another equation? Specifically, I am trying to include an equation for determining when to utilize the grid to cover shortages in meeting load requirements with renewable energy, or to sell excess energy back to the grid.
Given the equations:
P_Net(t) = Req_Load(t) - P_RE(t);

and
P_New(t) = P_Net(t) - [P_grid(t) * (1 - C_sell)];

I aim to set C_sell to zero in storage scenarios (P_Net >= 0) and C_sell = 1 when selling back to the grid (P_Net < 0). I attempted the following formulation:
Scalar C_sell /1/;
Eq_P_New(t).. P_New(t) = P_Net(t) - [P_grid(t) * (1 - C_sell$(P_Net.l(t) < 0))];

However, I encountered the following error message:

Endogenous $ operation not allowed.

While there are additional equations in my MiNLP model focused on minimizing total costs (multi-period optimization), I omitted them here for brevity.
Could you assist in resolving this error or suggest an alternative approach?
I tried converting the variable to scalars, but the solution stick to the scalars values.
I also tried to move the variables and equations in a loop to make it in the "if statement", but this did not work.
